# validateDOMNesting(...): <span> cannot appear as a child of <option>

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I am using `react-intl` for internalization.
I am getting the error `validateDOMNesting(...): <span> cannot appear as a child of <option>` for the following code.

I am not using span. But on inspection the element it is automatically taking span.

Here is the code:

```
<select onChange={this.localeChageHandler}>
   <option value="english">
      <FormattedMessage
        id="navigation.header.navbar.english"
        defaultMessage="English"
      />
   </option>
   <option value="hindi">
     <FormattedMessage id="navigation.header.navbar.hindi" defaultMessage="HIndi" />
   </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `FormattedMessage` will return span element, in order to ignore span element you have to pass options to children prop in `FormattedMessage`.

```
    <select onChange={this.localeChageHandler}>
              <FormattedMessage
                id="navigation.header.navbar.english"
                defaultMessage="English"
                children={
                  (formatedMessage) => <option value="English">{formatedMessage}</option>
                }
              />
          <FormattedMessage
                id="navigation.header.navbar.hindi"
                defaultMessage="HIndi"
                children= {
                  (formatedMessage) => <option value="HIndi">{formatedMessage}</option>
                }
              />
        </select>
```